# Putting a piece of code in between two html tags in Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris

On a solaris HTML file, how do I insert between an html tag and head tag? through bash scripting.

I have an html tag that looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:arf="http://scap.nist....-format/1.1" lang="en">
```

I want to insert a script written in text file, inside this 'SOLARIS' run HTML file, AFTER the long `<html....>` tag and BEFORE `<head>` tag, meaning BETWEEN the two tags, How do I do that?

I want to test using the bash commands to do it for one file at a time as well as multiple file in a folder directory. Will I have to use the folder path in my BASH code? Will I have to use FOR loop or interation in my BASH code? What would be the right code. Note: it is SOLARIS run html file not LINUX one. The name of my HTML file is `report.usc20.html`.

These are the lines of script that I want to use that are in my `backbutton_and_scroller_script.txt` file:

```
<div id="button"><a href="http://.....index.php">Back To The Hardening Page</a></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow78.js"></script>
<noscript>Not seeing a <a href="http://www.scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript>
```

Comment: Please be very specific in what you need to insert and where. This group is about Unix doubts, not about HTML. Please also add the HTML file and definite word/text examples of what you intend to do. This question is *extremely* vague.

Comment: There are some issues with posting html script on this site. I am rewriting this question right now. Unable to post html codes.

Comment: I have a javascript code that I want to insert in all html files in a folder between ..<html>.. and ..<head> tag. What Linux commands  do I need? to do it

Comment: Here is the code I wanted to add between <html> and <head> tags: "<div id="button"><a href="172.26.4.130/cfg2html_outputs/Hardening/php/… To The Hardening Page</a></div><script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/… type="text/javascript" src="arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow78.js"></… seeing a <a href="scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript> "

Comment: And do I need a pointer to all the html files?

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018 there are no issues with posting HTML on this site.  You enter the HTML, then you select it, and then you either press Ctrl-K or click on the icon that looks like `{}` in the editor - either of these will format the selected code as **code**.

Comment: Also, the way to do what you want to do on Solaris is the same as you'd do it in any other unix: if the HTML is reasonably valid XHTML then you can probably use an XML parser & editor like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`.  If it's the average malformed garbage that passes for a HTML in a web page then you'll have to write your own tool to do what you want in `perl` or `python` or some other language that has high-quality HTML parsing and generation libraries - e.g. `HTML::SimpleParse` or `HTML::Parser` or `HTML::Tree` in `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using `sed` (but with some gotchas to be aware of):

```
sed 's/<head/your-js-text<head/'
```

That will insert text before your `<head>` tag. The major 'gotcha' to be aware of is how to properly "escape" characters that are in your javascript that might be misinterpreted by `sed`, eg. the single quote, and the forward / backward slash. Also, on the off-chance that your html file is mal-formed, and includes more than one `<head>` tag, each will have the replacement made.

EDIT: If your javascript has many forward slashes in it, you can make use of a `sed` feature that allows a replacement character for the forward slash in the `s` command. Any of the following would also work:

```
sed 's^<head^your-js-text<head^'

sed 's%<head%your-js-text<head%'

sed 's#<head#your-js-text<head#'
```

Comment: For some reason it did not work. Here is the code I wanted to add between <html> and <head> tags: "<div id="button"><a href="http://172.26.4.130/cfg2html_outputs/Hardening/php/index.php">Back To The Hardening Page</a></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow78.js"></script><noscript>Not seeing a <a href="http://www.scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript> " Wanted to know do I cd the file path first before doing sed command.

Comment: And do I need a pointer to all the html files.

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018 - you have forward slashes in your script, which I said was something to worry about; did you try one of the alternatives? As for the html files, you list them as `sed` command parameters or pipe them into `sed`. If or once you are comfortable with the command, you can use the `-ibak` option to `sed` to edit each file in-place, and create a backup with the `bak` extension.

Comment: this is the error I am getting: sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command

Comment: cd /var/...../Hardening/
for i in *.html;
do sed 's#<head#
<div id="button">
<a href="http://172.26.4.130/cfg2html_outputs/Hardening/php/index.php">Back To The Hardening Page</a></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow78.js"></script>
<noscript>Not seeing a <a href="http://www.scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript>
<head#'; done . this is the code I am using what do you think?

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018 First try it with a short string to see that the technique works, and gradually lengthen it until you find the character that's giving you trouble, and then deal with it by escaping it with a backslash.

Comment: I have an issue my html files is a solaris run not Linux. Is their different type commands I will have to use? I tried even putting short characters it is still not working.

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018 Does this work? `printf "It does not work!\n" | sed 's/does not//;s/$/s/'`

Comment: Not it still doesn't work. it is giving me -bash: !\n": even not found. I posted a new question on the form to me more clear. My html files is a Solaris one not a Linux one.

Comment: Is there a way I can use perl scripting for this?

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018  Definitely, although I personally don't know perl.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/bash
while read line
do
echo $line
echo $line | grep -q "<html xmlns=".............." ............ lang="en">"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "<div id="button"><a href="http://..........index.php">Back To The Hardening Page</a></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow78.js"></script>
<noscript>Not seeing a <a href="http://www.scrolltotop.com/">Scroll to Top Button</a>? Go to our FAQ page for more info.</noscript>
" done < report.usc19.html

Comment: How can I make changes to this code I pasted in the comment so it works on SOLARIS. I got this code from Unix/Linux site. But I want it solaris style?

Comment: @XTERMINATOR2018 - What makes you think I know anything about solaris? You originally tagged the question `linux`, and just an hour ago switched it.

Comment: I thought it was the html file was Linux, but came to know it is Solaris later. Not assuming, just asking.

Comment: Hey how do I use you codes based on file name? meaning pointing towards specific file?